# Fit an ARIMA Model by Specifying the Parameters of AR and MA

Tags: r, arima

Using the `Arima()` function to fit an ARIMA model to a time series data, how can I specify the parameter of `AR` and `MA` in addition to the `order` of the model?

```
library(forecast)
set.seed(289805)
yt <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
(auto_fit <- auto.arima(yt))
#Series: yt 
#ARIMA(1,0,0) with zero mean 

#Coefficients:
#         ar1
#      0.8000
#s.e.  0.1458

#sigma^2 = 1.849:  log likelihood = -17.25
#AIC=38.49   AICc=40.21   BIC=39.1
Arima(yt, order = c(1, 0, 0))
#Series: yt 
#ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean 

#Coefficients:
#         ar1    mean
#      0.6258  1.5129
#s.e.  0.2416  0.9490

#sigma^2 = 1.929:  log likelihood = -16.61
#AIC=39.21   AICc=43.21   BIC=40.12
```

One can see that the coefficient of the `AR` is equal to 0.6258 with a mean equal to 1.5129.

**What I Want**

I want to be able to specify the parameter of the `AR` and `MA` when necessary in the `Arima()` function of the `forecast` package. Also, if there is a more convenient method that is different from the `Arima()` function. Take the below as an illustration of what I am trying to write:

```
Arima(yt, order = c(1, 0, 0), ar = c(0.8000))
#Error in stats::arima(x = x, order = order, seasonal = seasonal, include.mean = include.mean,  : 
#  unused argument (ar = 0.8)
```

I got the above error message.

**Another Way to Ask This Question**

If I can obtain the order of the `ARIMA` model as follows:

```
yt %>% auto.arima %>% arimaorder
#p d q 
#1 0 0
```

How best can I print out only the coefficient of the `AR` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the `AR` parameter of your `yt`, you could use the `coef` function to get a vector of the coefficients like this:

```r
library(forecast)
set.seed(289805)
yt <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.8, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
yt %>% auto.arima %>% coef
#> ar1 
#> 0.8
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>